# Angular 2+ tabs with routing in application

Tags: angular, url, tabs, router

im wondering how to do some kind of "internal tabs" in my application.

I want to have multiple tabs with multiple nested components (managed by router) and want to keep data alive when im moving between tabs (like keep data in forms etc.), but want to change URL in URL bar in browser.

Im talking about some kind of internal tabs in application, not multiple tabs in browser!

Do you have any tips how to achieve that? Did anybody made some kind of feature?

Thx

Comment: yes i have made but if you are routing and changing the URL then data will be lost.Another way is to hold the data in data services so you can reassign the that holded data to the component that loaded again

Comment: So, basic routing and singleton services ... Tabs being just differently-styled menus, you can refer to [the documentation of routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) and the [documentation of services](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: If you want to persist data between multiple component, consider implementing ngrx in your application

Comment: @Chellappan I strongly disagree with that. This implies a new learning curve for an optional library that isn't that suited for Angular.

Comment: @ShivShankarNamdev So basically, have a singleton instance of some data holding service... And everytime the tab changes, reload proper data from this data service and fill into form? I was thinking about this variant before i posted this topic, but i dont like one thing - it will be not type oriented (maybe i should use basic type "object" for storing data in service?)

Comment: @Maryannah, ya you are correct. It's not recommend using ngrx for state management of small and mid-size apps.

Comment: @Chellappan even on big projects this isn't advised. NgRx isn't necessary in Angular, where you have RxJS that can do the same job and doesn't require any new learning. This advice is typically made by people coming from outside of the Angular world (such as React) and from people that are used to use it. But it's very long & hard to learn, it just adds unecessary complexity !

Answer (score 1):

I do same functional in big project with multiple big components (CRM)

1. Each main component must have data service (in service u store only values from varibales)
2. All changes in component must work with data from data service
3. Each main component listen NavigationEnd and when it happens save data from data service to tab
4. When you return to this component from another at first u must set data from current active tab to your data service

[image: Example image from my project]